# Run Macro assigned to a slicer when changing any single value

Tags: excel, vba, selection, slicers

I have a slicer (based on a table), I would like to create a macro in order that when I select any single value in my slicer, the macro selects and copies automatically the second visible cell in column D (for example if I select the value `X13`[image] in my slicer, I want that my macro selects and copies automatically the second visible cell in column D). The part of my VBA code to select and copy the second visible cell in column D works perfectly but it does not work when I select a single value in my slicer (I assigned the macro related to my slicer). I do not know which line of VBA code that I need to add add for my macro works when I select any single value in my slicer. Please find my VBA code below.

```
Sub NextVisiblecellassignedtomyslicer()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("D1")
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    r.Copy
    Exit Sub
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find the solution to my problem by myself:

```
Sub NextVisiblecellassignedtomyslicer()
Dim slr As Slicer
Dim si As SlicerItem
Dim i As Long
Dim it As Object
Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WBS_element")

  With sc
 For Each it In .SlicerItems
If it.Selected = True Then
call nextvisiblecellV10
 End If
 Next it
  End With
End Sub
```

Sub nextvisiblecellV10()

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("D1")
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
r.Copy
Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```